# A generic error occurred in GDI+.in html code save image path into the project

Tags: c#

Haii..

Iam really struggling this error i tried all the links but iam not getting proper answer 
first i want to do i save my byte image value into project file folder 
i browse jpg image afer i asev into the project file path it throws the error
this is my code plase help me

```
             string converted = data.OfUploadsName.Replace('-', '+');
             converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
             string[] spilt=converted.Split(',');               
             byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(spilt[1]);             
             Image image;
             using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
             {
                 image = Image.FromStream(ms);
             }
             //0.5
             var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * 1);
             var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * 1);
             var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
             var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
             thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
             thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
             thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
             var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
             thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);

             thumbnailImg.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\SurveryDAL\Images\" + "'" + id + "'+.jpg"));
```

Comment: Several bugs.  The *using* statement is wrong, the stream must remain usable while you use the image you retrieved from the stream.  And you must use *using* to dispose the image, thumbnailImg and thumbGraph objects.  Failure to dispose thumbnailImg in particular leaves the file locked, liable to crash the code the next time.  You can get a better diagnostic for failure to create the file with File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]);

Comment: sorry iam not getting clearly plz expalin briefly

Comment: I cahnge the code like this but iam getting same error

Comment: string converted = data.OfUploadsName.Replace('-', '+');
                 converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
                 string[] spilt=converted.Split(',');               
                 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(spilt[1]);

                 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                 {
                                     using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
                     {
                         bm2.Save(@"\SurveryDAL\Images\" + "'" + id + "'+.jpg");
                     }
                 }